# Efficiently spawning sprites in Cocos2D

Tags: performance, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Just a quick question here; I have a background image in my game.  Every time I spawn an sprite, I use the [self addChild:@""]; statement.  Would it be more efficient to to call [backgroundImage addChild:@""]; instead?  I have tested both ways and they both work, but I cannot tell which is more efficient, or if it even makes a difference.

Thanks,

Tate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is CCLayer, calling [self addChild:img], the image will be added to the CCLayer.

I believe your background image is a CCSprite. [background addChild:img], will add the sprite to the background. If you adjust your background, like moving it up, all the sprites attached to background(child of background) would be moving together with the background image.

When you called [self removeChild:background], all the child attached to the background would be removed as well..

It depends on what are the requirements of the game.. =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So, it does not affect the performance or efficiency?

Comment: should not affect performance or whatever.. Just that be careful when you removing/calling the sprites. Better to attach to the layer rather than the backgrd sprite.

Comment: Also, sprites not on the screen use very little CPU, so you don't need to hide them or anything like that. However, if they run an update/tick method that you don't need, it's better to stop these with `pauseSchedulerAndActions` and `resumeSchedulerAndActions`.